# Windows 10 (and 11) Shell Corruption?

Tags: windows-10, shell, windows-11, gui

Has anyone encountered issues in Windows 10 (and Windows 11) where the shell seems to become corrupted? Here are some examples of symptoms:

- can't scroll start menu (in Win10)
- can't scroll Settings menu (or sub-menus, such as when clicking on System -> Display and then attempting to scroll that window)
- pop-out notifications can't be dismissed by dragging them to the right

I've noticed this on a few systems over the years, and even just recently tried to update one to Win11 to see if that resolved the issue, but still experiencing shell issues - the start menu won't even launch, the Settings app is still all screwed up, etc.

If anyone has any tips on how to resolve (short of wiping entire computer and reinstalling OS), they would definitely be appreciated. At one point I thought they might be user profile corruptions, but in the most recent instance I created a brand new user profile and it still experienced the same problems.

Comment: Yes. Windows 10 not 11.  Shell Context error.  See if you can find it with Nirsoft Shell View.  Difficult context errors are best solved by reinstalling Windows

Comment: "the start menu won't even launch, the Settings app is still all screwed up, etc." - An issue like this typically is easily resolved by an in-place installation of Windows, allowing you to keep your software and personal files, but refreshing any system issues that might exist.  However, the start menu not working, indicates you have software installed causing the problem.  So have we seen this problem, there are literally hundreds of questions about the start menu not working, and in all cases it's always caused by a system configuration issue,

Comment: After some further research (https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2288677-unable-to-scroll-settings-start-menu-etc-windows-10), it appears this issue might be related to video drivers and the laptop lid being closed (and that I'm only noticing this issue when remotely connected to laptop when lid is closed, and laptop is configured to not go into sleep mode when lid is closed).  I had someone open the laptop lid (since I was not on-site) and then everything seemed to work correctly again.